# Paragraph indentation after lstlisting environments

Tags: listings, environments, indentation, paragraphs

I tried to indent first paragraph after a customized `lstlisting` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum}
\lstnewenvironment{mycode}{}{\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mycode}
\def\cmd#1{\cs{\expandafter\cmd@to@cs\string#1}}
\def\cmd@to@cs#1#2{\char\number`#2\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\end{mycode}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

But the above code fails. How could I fix the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `etoolbox` and its `\AfterEndEnvironment` hook to insert `\par`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum}
\lstnewenvironment{mycode}{}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mycode}{\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mycode}
\def\cmd#1{\cs{\expandafter\cmd@to@cs\string#1}}
\def\cmd@to@cs#1#2{\char\number`#2\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\end{mycode}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just leave a blank line after the environment, if you want indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum}
\lstnewenvironment{mycode}{}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{mycode}
\def\cmd#1{\cs{\expandafter\cmd@to@cs\string#1}}
\def\cmd@to@cs#1#2{\char\number`#2\relax}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\end{mycode}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]